# Python compile error on openSUSE: no module named wx

Tags: linux, compiling, opensuse, python

I'm new to Linux. After installing openSUSE I'm trying to make my VPN software running. I've followed the site's direction:

```
Unpack the general package [[Other / Source code](https://mullvad.net/static/download/mullvad-43.tar.gz)], install OpenVPN and
resolvconf and start it like this: `sudo python mullvad.py`.
```

But when I type that in terminal, I get this error: `no module named wx`.

I have already spent a lot of time figuring out how to compile it, to no avail. Before I turn to another Linux distribution or go back to Windows, it would be grateful if anyone could answer these questions: 
What is `wx module` and how can I add it? And, is the tool for compiling it in openSUSE at all?

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please mark the best solution. If not, then please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You should just install package named python-wxwidgets, which is available in openSuse.

Comment: Welcome to Unix and Linux, milos.  You can improve this answer by explicit writing the command needed to install `python-wxwidgets` in openSuse.

Answer (score 0):

wxwidgets is a simple tool kit for making quick GUIs.

In OpenSuSE you can install it with the following:

`zypper in python-wxWidgets` as root

After that, you'll be able to run it with no problem.

If you are still having problems, make sure the "openSUSE-*-Oss" repo is enabled. Where * is your distro number.

Answer (score -1):

You want wxpython, which apparently isn't available for openSUSE. You can follow [instructions on their website](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython) to build it from source. Roughly:

```
$ ./configure --with-gtk
$ make
$ su
# make install
# ldconfig
```

Comment: It is available, it just needs to be installed. It is called python-wxWidgets.